# Does PathView in QML work on interpolation?

Tags: javascript, qml

Am just curious to know how the PathView uses the PathLine element to form itself?

Answer (score 0):

It is based on QPainterPath: http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qpainterpath.html

PathLine, PathQuad, etc. are combined into a single QPainterPath which can be give a position at any point along the path via QPainterPath::pointAtPercent().

The actual implementation caches a number of points to speed up the lookup.  In QtQuick 2.0 the point returned is an interpolation of the two nearest cached points.